# Keep a randomly generated HTML background static for the duration of a session?

Tags: html, wordpress, session, variables

I have a wordpress site that generates a random background on the homepage. Each time the user clicks through various parts of the site, I would like to keep this background the same until the user clicks on the homepage again.

I have thought of a number of possible solutions:

- AJAX calls loading the content of various clicks into a div (not ideal as it gets complicated quickly with trying to manage friendly urls, plugins that call their own ajax data etc)
- A cookie that saves the background html into it and expires quickly or when reloading the homepage.
- A POST variable that holds the background html between the various parts of the site.

The primary goal is to keep a background that is randomly generated on the homepage but remains the same while using the website. Can anyone recommend a better solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you generating your background on the home page? And if a user comes back to your site the next day but doesn't go straight to the home page should it generate a new background or use the same one as the day before?

Comment: The background is just a random selection of images from a folder on the server. If the user is simply visiting any other page, not through the homepage, it is fine if the background is regenerated. The background should just be generated whenever the user visits the site, just not when clicking through links within it.

Answer (score 0):

you could either do it via cookies or GET Parameter. The cookie solution takes more effort on JavaScript side. And some users do not like cookies, but that should not be a big deal.

You could prepare all the impacted links like so `http://www.example.com?bgimg=bigblackdog`
and then set the image via wordpress php code or maybe js if you want to.